# How to include position number in str() output?

Tags: r

I was wondering whether anybody has a neat solution for including position numbers of variables when getting `str` output.

Example:

Instead of getting this:

```
str(cars) 
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ speed: num  4 4 7 7 8 9 10 10 10 11 ...
 $ dist : num  2 10 4 22 16 10 18 26 34 17 ...
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
str(cars) 
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  2 variables:
 1 speed: num  4 4 7 7 8 9 10 10 10 11 ...
 2 dist : num  2 10 4 22 16 10 18 26 34 17 ...
```

in order to be able to index data.frames more easily.

Comment: just count??? the order of the variables is the same as the order of the columns

Comment: Counting becomes annoying when you're dealing with more than 90 variables or so...

Comment: this is why you use data.table which takes names as an input or select from dplyr, which is better coding-practice anyway

Comment: data.frames take names as an input too. I'l check out data.tables, but I'm normally against loading to many packages. Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hastily modified version of `glimpse` from `dplyr` which does what you need:

```
library(dplyr)

glimpse_n <- function(tbl, width = getOption("width")) {
    cat("Observations: ", nrow(tbl), "\n", sep = "")
    if (ncol(tbl) == 0) 
        return(invisible())
    cat("Variables:\n")
    rows <- as.integer(width/3)
    df <- as.data.frame(head(tbl, rows))
    var_types <- vapply(df, type_sum, character(1))
    var_names <- paste0(sprintf("%3d ", 1:length(names(df))), format(names(df)), " (", var_types, 
        ") ")
    data_width <- width - nchar(var_names) - 2
    length_est <- pmin(ceiling(max(data_width)/3) + 1, nrow(tbl))
    formatted <- vapply(df, function(x) paste0(dplyr:::format_v(x), collapse = ", "), 
        character(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    truncated <- dplyr:::str_trunc(formatted, data_width)
    cat(paste0(var_names, truncated, collapse = "\n"), "\n", 
        sep = "")
}

glimpse_n(mtcars)

## Observations: 32
## Variables:
##   1 mpg  (dbl) 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 1...
##   2 cyl  (dbl) 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8...
##   3 disp (dbl) 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 140.8, 167....
##   4 hp   (dbl) 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180, ...
##   5 drat (dbl) 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 3...
##   6 wt   (dbl) 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.190, 3.150, 3.44...
##   7 qsec (dbl) 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.00, 22.90, 18.3...
##   8 vs   (dbl) 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0...
##   9 am   (fctr) 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...
##  10 gear (dbl) 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3...
##  11 carb (dbl) 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2...
```